# Have to make Address Book with javaFX Search And Delete Button

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am trying to make an address book containing some Person info With `Add`, `Edit`, `Search` & `Delete` options. See below.

1. Search Button: If user add some info in blocks then instead of
   pressing `Add` if its press `Search` then info will display accordingly
2. Delete Button: If user selects some row i.e one person's details then
   after pressing delete button it show what will be deleted from data.
3. Am Trying To Get Values From ComboBox After i add ComboBox in add button            But its not Storing ComboBOx Value in tablecell.

My Problem Is When I add or Delete Some PersonData from table then it will delete but updating on after i press search button why its happens.

My Current Code Till Yet
Please help.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class MyAddressBook extends Application {

// for delete selection
private IntegerProperty index = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
// for Filter
private ObservableList<Person> filteredList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList
    (new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "Male","12 HouseNo 35Street Newyork", " 1234341", "12-01-1867","jacob.smith@example.com"),
     new Person("Isabella","Johnson", "Female", "6 HouseNo 10Street California"," 9876521", "12-01-1885", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
     new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "Male","3 Villa House 3Street LosAngels", " 1122331","01-10-1871", "ethan.williams@example.com"));

final HBox hb = new HBox();

public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
}

public final double getIndex() {
    return index.get();
}

public final void setIndex(Integer value) {
    index.set(value);
}

public IntegerProperty indexProperty() {
    return index;
}

public void filterPerson(Person filteringPerson) {
    // first clear the data in the table.
    filteredList.clear();
    Iterator<Person> completeData = data.iterator();
    while (completeData.hasNext()) {
        Person person = (Person) completeData.next();
        // if the first name matches searching person name, then add it to
        if (person.getFirstName().contains(filteringPerson.getFirstName())) {
            this.filteredList.add(person);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    stage.setTitle("Address Book");
    stage.setWidth(900);
    stage.setHeight(550);

    final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    ComboBox genderComboBox = new ComboBox();
    genderComboBox.getItems().addAll("Male", "Female");
    genderComboBox.setValue("Male");
    genderComboBox
            .setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
                    final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
                        {
                            super.setPrefWidth(100);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            if (item != null) {
                                setText(item);
                                if (item.contains("Male")) {
                                    setTextFill(Color.RED);
                                } else if (item.contains("Female")) {
                                    setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
                                } else {
                                    setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                                }
                            } else {
                                setText(null);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    return cell;
                }
            });

    table.setEditable(true);
    TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>(
            "First Name");
    firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    firstNameCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
    // firstNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    firstNameCol
            .setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems()
                            .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                            .setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
                }
            });

    TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    lastNameCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));
    lastNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    lastNameCol
            .setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems()
                            .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                            .setLastName(t.getNewValue());
                }
            });

    TableColumn genderCol = new TableColumn("Gender");
    genderCol.setMinWidth(10);
    genderCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("gender"));
    genderCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    genderCol
            .setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems()
                            .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                            .setGender(t.getNewValue());
                }
            });

    TableColumn addressCol = new TableColumn("Address");
    addressCol.setMinWidth(200);
    addressCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("address"));
    addressCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    addressCol
            .setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems()
                            .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                            .setAddress(t.getNewValue());
                }
            });

    TableColumn phoneNoCol = new TableColumn("Phone No");
    phoneNoCol.setMinWidth(100);
    phoneNoCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("phoneNo"));
    phoneNoCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    phoneNoCol
            .setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems()
                            .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                            .setPhoneNo(t.getNewValue());
                }
            });

    TableColumn dateOfBirthCol = new TableColumn("Date Of Birth");
    dateOfBirthCol.setMinWidth(100);
    dateOfBirthCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("dateOfBirth"));
    dateOfBirthCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    dateOfBirthCol
            .setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems()
                            .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                            .setDateOfBirth(t.getNewValue());
                }
            });

    TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
    emailCol.setMinWidth(150);
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));
    emailCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    emailCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
            ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems()
                    .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setEmail(t
                    .getNewValue());
        }
    });

    table.setItems(filteredList);
    filteredList.addAll(data);
    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, genderCol,
            addressCol, phoneNoCol, dateOfBirthCol, emailCol);

    final TextField addFirstName = new TextField();
    addFirstName.setPromptText("First Name");
    addFirstName.setMaxWidth(firstNameCol.getPrefWidth());
    final TextField addLastName = new TextField();
    addLastName.setMaxWidth(lastNameCol.getPrefWidth());
    addLastName.setPromptText("Last Name");

    final TextField addGender = new TextField();
    addGender.setMaxWidth(genderCol.getPrefWidth());
    addGender.setPromptText("Gender");

    final TextField addAddress = new TextField();
    addAddress.setMaxWidth(addressCol.getPrefWidth());
    addAddress.setPromptText("Address");
    final TextField addPhoneNo = new TextField();
    addPhoneNo.setMaxWidth(phoneNoCol.getPrefWidth());
    addPhoneNo.setPromptText("PhoneNo");
    final TextField addDateOfBirth = new TextField();
    addDateOfBirth.setMaxWidth(dateOfBirthCol.getPrefWidth());
    addDateOfBirth.setPromptText("DateOfBirth");
    final TextField addEmail = new TextField();
    addEmail.setMaxWidth(emailCol.getPrefWidth());
    addEmail.setPromptText("Email");

    final Button addButton = new Button("Add");
    addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            data.add(new Person(addFirstName.getText(), addLastName.getText(), addAddress.getText(), addPhoneNo.getText(),
                    addDateOfBirth.getText(), addEmail.getText(), addGender.getText()));

            addFirstName.clear();
            addLastName.clear();
            addAddress.clear();
            addPhoneNo.clear();
            addDateOfBirth.clear();
            addEmail.clear();
            addGender.clear();
        }
    });

    table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
            .addListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue observable,
                        Object oldvalue, Object newValue) {
                    Person selectedPerson = (Person) newValue;
                    setIndex(data.indexOf(newValue));
                    System.out.println("OK");
                }
            });

    final Button delButton = new Button("Delete");
    delButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            data.remove(index.get());
            table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        }
    });

    final Button searchButton = new Button("Search");
    searchButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            Person person = new Person(addFirstName.getText(), addLastName.getText(), addAddress.getText(), addPhoneNo.getText(),
                    addDateOfBirth.getText(), addEmail.getText(), addGender.getText());
            addFirstName.clear();
            addLastName.clear();
            addAddress.clear();
            addPhoneNo.clear();
            addDateOfBirth.clear();
            addEmail.clear();
            addGender.clear();
            filterPerson(person);
        }
    });

    hb.getChildren().addAll(addFirstName, addLastName, genderComboBox,addAddress, addPhoneNo, addDateOfBirth, addEmail, addButton,
            delButton, searchButton);
    hb.setSpacing(3);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hb);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty gender;
    private final SimpleStringProperty address;
    private final SimpleStringProperty phoneNo;
    private final SimpleStringProperty dateOfBirth;
    private final SimpleStringProperty email;

    private Person(String fName, String lName, String gen, String address, String phNo, String dob, String email) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        this.gender = new SimpleStringProperty(gen);
        this.address = new SimpleStringProperty(address);
        this.phoneNo = new SimpleStringProperty(phNo);
        this.dateOfBirth = new SimpleStringProperty(dob);
        this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fName) {
        firstName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String fName) {
        lastName.set(fName);
    }

    public void setGender(String gen) {
        gender.set(gen);
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender.get();
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address.get();
    }

    public void setAddress(String add) {
        address.set(add);
    }

    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo.get();
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(String phNo) {
        phoneNo.set(phNo);
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth.get();
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dob) {
        dateOfBirth.set(dob);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email.get();
    }

    public void setEmail(String fName) {
        email.set(fName);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return firstName.get().compareToIgnoreCase(o.getFirstName());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: sorry I can't add picture here because am newbie here so You can Check out by Compile it Address Book Generate and Read Above Info Please.

Comment: English, formatting.

Answer (score 0):

This creates the button

```
final Button addButton = new Button("Add");
    addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            data.add(new Person(
                    addFirstName.getText(),
                    addLastName.getText(),
                    addAddress.getText(),
                    addPhoneNo.getText(),
                    addDateOfBirth.getText(),
                    addEmail.getText(),
                    addGender.getText()));
            addFirstName.clear();
            addLastName.clear();
            addAddress.clear();
            addPhoneNo.clear();
            addDateOfBirth.clear();
            addEmail.clear();
            addGender.clear();
        }
    });
```

and this line added all elements to the scene

```
hb.getChildren().addAll(addFirstName, addLastName, addGender, addAddress, addPhoneNo, addDateOfBirth, addEmail, addButton);
```

So create your Buttons

```
final Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete");
    addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            // Delete your date here
        }
    });
```

and add it to the list like

```
hb.getChildren().addAll(addFirstName, addLastName, addGender, addAddress, addPhoneNo, addDateOfBirth, addEmail, addButton, deleteButton, searchButton);
```

Comment: Thank You for Responding Bro. I got Know Basic knowledg about Add button Delete Button Is i will handle am working on it i think java have core class & fuction for my problem

Comment: JacKTools.Net can you tell me about how to manage Search or Filter please am stuck on it

Comment: Create a secound  private final ObservableList<Person> searchResult = ... Use a for luup to find hits at your data list and create an item in searchResult list for each hit. Set  table.setItems(data); to  table.setItems(searchResult); Create a show all button to set the view back to  table.setItems(data); and clear the searchREsult list.

Comment: [code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering] i real this link Several Times And Try to compile this example But not understanding for me..
If you can Di-scribe with some piece of code then its helpful for me

Comment: One more thing Bro I want to add ComboBox in my gender textfield how can i do This code how i implement text Field

    ObservableList<String> options = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        "Option 1",
        "Option 2",
        "Option 3"
    );
    final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(options);

Comment: I guess when my assignment submission time is of then i got answer of these problems

Comment: Why would you add a combobox to a text field. I don't know if this is possible. Has textfield a getChildren method?

Comment: no its not getting children method when i add genderComboBox.getText  then show error:  not find getText() method ..

if i made a custom comboBox and i add it in getChildren().addAll(
 how would i getvalue from comboBox & show it in tablegender because getText or getValue are not in comboBox Method

Comment: What you want is to get the Text from the Item that is selelected. .getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: Bro can you tell me some for my current problem add delete search buttons working good but every time to update tableView i need to press search button how can i fix it .. I edit my old post check new one's please.

Comment: When you add edit or delete something Set the Table view to your original observable list. Use the filtered list only if you filter something.

Comment: //table.setItems(filteredList);
 table.setItems(data);
    filteredList.addAll(data);
    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, genderCol,addressCol, phoneNoCol, dateOfBirthCol, emailCol);
Am doing like this after this add & delete button are good and updating but searchButton not showing search result if i don't do this then add & delete button need search button to display data

Answer (score 0):

This is for searchButton : 
create method called applyFilter(Person person) : which filters the 'data' of the table view based on the values that are present in person.
Call this method in the action event of the searchButton. 
have another list

```
private ObservableList<Person>  filteredList= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

1)instead of adding the 'data' to table, add 'filteredList' to Tableview 
2) now add all the items of 'data' to filteredList

```
tableView.setItems(filteredList);
filteredList.addAll(data);
```

Ex:

```
 final Button searchButton = new Button("search");
    searchButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            Person person = new Person(
                    addFirstName.getText(),
                    addLastName.getText(),
                    addAddress.getText(),
                    addPhoneNo.getText(),
                    addDateOfBirth.getText(),
                    addEmail.getText(),
                    addGender.getText());
            addFirstName.clear();
            addLastName.clear();
            addAddress.clear();
            addPhoneNo.clear();
            addDateOfBirth.clear();
            addEmail.clear();
            addGender.clear();
            filterPerson(person);
        }
    });
```

the filtering method is

```
protected void filterPerson( Person filteringPerson ){
    // first clear the data in the table.
    filteredList.clear();
    Iterator<Person> completeData = data.iterator();
    while( completeData.hasNext() ){
        Person person = (Person) completeData.next();
        // if the first name matches searching person name, then add  it to      
        if(person.getFirstName().contains( filteringPerson.getFirstName() )){
            this.filteredList.add( person );
        }
    }
```

}

```
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class MyAddressBook extends Application {

// for delete selection
private IntegerProperty index = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
// for Filter
private ObservableList<Person> filteredList = FXCollections
        .observableArrayList();

private final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections
        .observableArrayList(new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "Male",
                "12 HouseNo 35Street Newyork", " 1234341", "12-01-1867",
                "jacob.smith@example.com"), new Person("Isabella",
                "Johnson", "Female", "6 HouseNo 10Street California",
                " 9876521", "12-01-1885", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "Male",
                        "3 Villa House 3Street LosAngels", " 1122331",
                        "01-10-1871", "ethan.williams@example.com"));
final HBox hb = new HBox();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public final double getIndex() {
    return index.get();
}

public final void setIndex(Integer value) {
    index.set(value);
}

public IntegerProperty indexProperty() {
    return index;
}

public void filterPerson(Person filteringPerson) {
    // first clear the data in the table.
    filteredList.clear();
    Iterator<Person> completeData = data.iterator();
    while (completeData.hasNext()) {
        Person person = (Person) completeData.next();
        // if the first name matches searching person name, then add it to
        if (person.getFirstName().contains(filteringPerson.getFirstName())) {
            this.filteredList.add(person);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    stage.setTitle("Address Book");
    stage.setWidth(900);
    stage.setHeight(550);

    final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    ComboBox genderComboBox = new ComboBox();
    genderComboBox.getItems().addAll("Male", "Female");
    genderComboBox.setValue("Male");
    genderComboBox
            .setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
                    final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
                        {
                            super.setPrefWidth(100);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            if (item != null) {
                                setText(item);
                                if (item.contains("Male")) {
                                    setTextFill(Color.RED);
                                } else if (item.contains("Female")) {
                                    setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
                                } else {
                                    setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                                }
                            } else {
                                setText(null);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    return cell;
                }
            });

    table.setEditable(true);
    TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>(
            "First Name");
    firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    firstNameCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>(
                    "firstName"));
    // firstNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    firstNameCol
            .setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems()
                            .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                            .setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
                }
            });

    TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    lastNameCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>(
                    "lastName"));
    lastNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    lastNameCol
            .setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems()
                            .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                            .setLastName(t.getNewValue());
                }
            });

    TableColumn genderCol = new TableColumn("Gender");
    genderCol.setMinWidth(10);
    genderCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>(
            "gender"));
    genderCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    genderCol
            .setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems()
                            .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                            .setGender(t.getNewValue());
                }
            });

    TableColumn addressCol = new TableColumn("Address");
    addressCol.setMinWidth(200);
    addressCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>(
                    "address"));
    addressCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    addressCol
            .setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems()
                            .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                            .setAddress(t.getNewValue());
                }
            });

    TableColumn phoneNoCol = new TableColumn("Phone No");
    phoneNoCol.setMinWidth(100);
    phoneNoCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>(
                    "phoneNo"));
    phoneNoCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    phoneNoCol
            .setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems()
                            .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                            .setPhoneNo(t.getNewValue());
                }
            });

    TableColumn dateOfBirthCol = new TableColumn("Date Of Birth");
    dateOfBirthCol.setMinWidth(100);
    dateOfBirthCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>(
                    "dateOfBirth"));
    dateOfBirthCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    dateOfBirthCol
            .setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems()
                            .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                            .setDateOfBirth(t.getNewValue());
                }
            });

    TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
    emailCol.setMinWidth(150);
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>(
            "email"));
    emailCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    emailCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
            ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems()
                    .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setEmail(t
                    .getNewValue());
        }
    });

    table.setItems(filteredList);
    filteredList.addAll(data);
    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, genderCol,
            addressCol, phoneNoCol, dateOfBirthCol, emailCol);

    final TextField addFirstName = new TextField();
    addFirstName.setPromptText("First Name");
    addFirstName.setMaxWidth(firstNameCol.getPrefWidth());
    final TextField addLastName = new TextField();
    addLastName.setMaxWidth(lastNameCol.getPrefWidth());
    addLastName.setPromptText("Last Name");
    final TextField addGender = new TextField();
    addGender.setMaxWidth(genderCol.getPrefWidth());
    addGender.setPromptText("Gender");
    final TextField addAddress = new TextField();
    addAddress.setMaxWidth(addressCol.getPrefWidth());
    addAddress.setPromptText("Address");
    final TextField addPhoneNo = new TextField();
    addPhoneNo.setMaxWidth(phoneNoCol.getPrefWidth());
    addPhoneNo.setPromptText("PhoneNo");
    final TextField addDateOfBirth = new TextField();
    addDateOfBirth.setMaxWidth(dateOfBirthCol.getPrefWidth());
    addDateOfBirth.setPromptText("DateOfBirth");
    final TextField addEmail = new TextField();
    addEmail.setMaxWidth(emailCol.getPrefWidth());
    addEmail.setPromptText("Email");

    final Button addButton = new Button("Add");
    addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            data.add(new Person(addFirstName.getText(), addLastName
                    .getText(), addAddress.getText(), addPhoneNo.getText(),
                    addDateOfBirth.getText(), addEmail.getText(), addGender
                            .getText()));
            addFirstName.clear();
            addLastName.clear();
            addAddress.clear();
            addPhoneNo.clear();
            addDateOfBirth.clear();
            addEmail.clear();
            addGender.clear();
        }
    });

    table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
            .addListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue observable,
                        Object oldvalue, Object newValue) {
                    Person selectedPerson = (Person) newValue;
                    setIndex(data.indexOf(newValue));
                    System.out.println("OK");
                }
            });

    final Button delButton = new Button("Delete");
    delButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            data.remove(index.get());
            table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        }
    });

    final Button searchButton = new Button("Search");
    searchButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            Person person = new Person(addFirstName.getText(), addLastName
                    .getText(), addAddress.getText(), addPhoneNo.getText(),
                    addDateOfBirth.getText(), addEmail.getText(), addGender
                            .getText());
            addFirstName.clear();
            addLastName.clear();
            addAddress.clear();
            addPhoneNo.clear();
            addDateOfBirth.clear();
            addEmail.clear();
            addGender.clear();
            filterPerson(person);
        }
    });

    hb.getChildren().addAll(addFirstName, addLastName, genderComboBox,
            addAddress, addPhoneNo, addDateOfBirth, addEmail, addButton,
            delButton, searchButton);
    hb.setSpacing(3);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hb);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty gender;
    private final SimpleStringProperty address;
    private final SimpleStringProperty phoneNo;
    private final SimpleStringProperty dateOfBirth;
    private final SimpleStringProperty email;

    private Person(String fName, String lName, String gen, String address,
            String phNo, String dob, String email) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        this.gender = new SimpleStringProperty(gen);
        this.address = new SimpleStringProperty(address);
        this.phoneNo = new SimpleStringProperty(phNo);
        this.dateOfBirth = new SimpleStringProperty(dob);
        this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fName) {
        firstName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String fName) {
        lastName.set(fName);
    }

    public void setGender(String gen) {
        gender.set(gen);
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender.get();
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address.get();
    }

    public void setAddress(String add) {
        address.set(add);
    }

    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo.get();
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(String phNo) {
        phoneNo.set(phNo);
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth.get();
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dob) {
        dateOfBirth.set(dob);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email.get();
    }

    public void setEmail(String fName) {
        email.set(fName);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return firstName.get().compareToIgnoreCase(o.getFirstName());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: bro i don't now why it is happing with me that is if i add search button in program even with no arg just you show above then when i test search button is made but addbutton is distrub & not personData is adding in table but if i comments the searchbutton eventhandler () then its starting add again ...?

Comment: Thanks bro for Helping me I try this code almost easy to understand but when i try to add code my addressbook filterPerson() is returning error.. its expecting ";" this what is wrong with this filterPerson()..

Comment: Check out My current Updated Code Bro If i added filterPerson in control class and call filterPerson() in after search Button error am getting in here addEmail.clear();
            addGender.clear();
        --->    filterPerson(person);
        Cannot find person variable

Comment: add action to searchButton, instead you added to addButton. And set filteredList as items for tableView. I have edited my post

Comment: Bro after i edit in my code as you say in add filteredList to tableView.. But after then i got two errors "tableView Variable not found " & last error of what am getting since from yesterday that is "filterPerson(person)   cannot find person variable"

Comment: thankyou bro for help ... i check code as you saying and filterlist to tableView and its compiling good know can you tell me please why showing error for "Person variable not found" before your editing. Yet Search System Working good

Comment: Bro after editing code i got some new problem that is "indexArrayBoundException" is Found when i try to delete any selected row because its indicated to -1 index so how can i fix..i think i have to add try catch block for indexboundException But i want to know it should write on Try{ deleteButton }catch like this ..?

Comment: Any solution for these problems bro

Comment: its not a good way to add exception block, instead if index is -1, show error message to user that the table is empty.

Comment: bro problem is that i need to press searchButton every time to see new records in table after searchFiltering(person) button is edit as you say.

Comment: Bro i have custom comboBox in my code. It can be add in getChildren() but i can't add it into table.getColumn.add(column's) So how can i getValue from comboBox which are in getChildren() and how i display it into tableColumn